# How to fetch all other column values with group by columns

Tags: sql

How to fetch other column values which are there apart from group by as below,

```
SELECT DIS.iDataItemID, 
DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID, 
COUNT(*) , 
DI.iDataTypeID,
DI.iEmployeeID,
DI.iEmployerID
FROM DataItem DI INNER JOIN DataItemStatus DIS 
ON DI.iDataItemID = DIS.iDataItemID Where iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 1
GROUP BY DIS.iDataItemID, DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID
```

Query works fine, if i remove the three columns from select (i.e. iDataTypeID, iEmployeeID, iEmployerID)

Please let me know, how to fetch the result with these values

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

When using a `group by`, for your SQL to be valid you need to either use an aggregate (`count`, `max`) either have the column in the `group by` list (MySQL is an exception in this regard if strict mode is not enforced).

I short, just add the 3 extra columns you want to see at the end of your current `group by` line:

```
SELECT DIS.iDataItemID, 
DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID, 
COUNT(*) , 
DI.iDataTypeID,
DI.iEmployeeID,
DI.iEmployerID
FROM DataItem DI INNER JOIN DataItemStatus DIS 
ON DI.iDataItemID = DIS.iDataItemID Where iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 1
GROUP BY DIS.iDataItemID, DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID, DI.iDataTypeID, 
DI.iEmployeeID, DI.iEmployerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of `DBMS` has *window* function support :

```
SELECT DIS.iDataItemID, DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DIS.iDataItemID, DIS.iDataItemCurrentStatusID), 
       DI.iDataTypeID,
       DI.iEmployeeID,
       DI.iEmployerID
FROM DataItem DI INNER JOIN 
     DataItemStatus DIS 
     ON DI.iDataItemID = DIS.iDataItemID 
WHERE iDataItemCurrentStatusID = 1;
```

I assume your `DB` is also one of them which has window function support.